# Chrome doesn't render marquee inside a table properly, while Firefox does

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, marquee

I have an iframe on my page inside which some html is loaded. I am able to modify the loaded contents of the iframe from my page using javascript.

One of the elements inside the loaded html is a marquee inside a table cell. The text of the marquee is very long. I want the size of the marquee to depend on the size of the other rows in the table, i.e. not have any specific size of its own but fill the container in which it is located. The Firefox does it perfectly.

However the same code renders awfully in Chrome. Chrome forces the marquee width to be of the size of the text. That is if there is a lot of text in the marquee the marquee width will become huge.

How can I make it so that Chrome renders the html the same way as firefox, i.e. so that marquee has a reasonable size?

One way that I tried to solve it is by modifying width of the marquee inside the iframe from my page. However when I do that, the size of the marquee decreases, but the text still acts like it is far away from the marque. That is I have to wait a lot for the text to reach the shrinked marquee window.
I think this is because there is some delay between the time the iframe is loaded and the time that the marquee size is modified by javascript from my page. Because of the delay marquee has already decided its size and the text is located in such a way as if the marquee is very wide, and even if the size of marque changes later, the text somehow doesn't know about it.

Below is the code, and here is the jsfiddle of that code: http://jsfiddle.net/vk8ucqpq/

P.S. I know that marquee is old technology and I shouldn't be using it, but I must use it for legacy reasons. Also, I can't take the marquee out of the table cell, it must remain inside the table. It should also be noted that when the marquee is not inside the table, then Chrome renders it correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <marquee >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit
 amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum
 dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem
 ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit
 amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
    </marquee>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but your code snippet is working.. just clicked on run

Comment: @PushkerYadav If you open it in latest Chrome, the marquee width is huge, don't you see it?